# In pyautogui, it seems to be running in only one window

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am making a bot at the moment using pyautogui. When I run it in pycharm, it clicks on wherever my mouse is after 10 seconds, but if I use it on google, it runs but does not click. here is the code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(10)
while True:
    pyautogui.click()
```

does anyone know how to fix this (btw i'm using chromebook)

Comment: 3 things. First - It's not a good idea to use an infinite loop in this case. Add a terminating if clause inside the while loop, or just use a for loop for some number of iterations. Second - are you manually positioning the cursor onto a button, or something. If not, then on on what basis do you believe it's not clicking? Third - Add a time.sleep after every iteration, otherwise your device will just... freeze. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I meant to take take the loop out, soz. also, its meant to play the dinosaur game, so i positioned my mouse on a button before.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me, though.

Comment: for scripts with pyautogui, you have to run it as admin